# How can I replace values in a range of time with their mean with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have data that looks like this:

```
    timestamp  value
0       12345    0.0
1       12346    1.0
2       12347    4.0
3       12348    2.0
4       12349    6.0
...
```

and I want to turn it into e.g something like this:

```
    timestamp  value
0       12345    0.5
1       12346    0.5
2       12347    3.0
3       12348    3.0
4       12349    6.0
...
```

I want to reduce the "resolution" of my values by replacing them with the mean of a certain time range. This is similar to:

```
df = df.groupby(df.index // N).mean()
```

Where N is the number of rows to mean, except that:

1. I want to preserve the number of rows (aka in pandas: "pad"/"ffill" those means).
2. Related to (1), the timestamps should remain untouched, rather than get mean'd along with the values.
3. Ideally I don't want to group by N rows, but rather time ranges (e.g. minutes, hours, days) since I can't guarantee that the timestamps are equally spaced.

I realise this is a bit complicated, and can be done in a variety of different steps, but I'm new at using pandas and was hoping there are simpler built-in steps. Any pointers much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
In [12]: df['value'] = df['value'].groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // N).transform('mean')
In [13]: df
Out[13]:
   timestamp  value
0    12345    0.5
1    12346    0.5
2    12347    3.0
3    12348    3.0
4    12349    6.0
```